# Binomial Expansion rth term

Tags: algebra-precalculus, binomial-theorem

> Given that there's no term on $x^3$ in $$(k + 2x) (1 - 3/2 x) ^6.$$ Evaluate the value of $k$

Difficult

After expanding $(1 - 3/2 x)^6$ up to the 3rd term I get $1 - 9x + \frac{135}{2} x^2 - \frac{135}{4} x^3 + \ldots$ 
What do I do next to solve this question??

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

The terms with $x^3$ are

$$k\cdot \binom{6}{3}\cdot 1^3\cdot \left(-\frac 32\right)^3\cdot x^3$$ and

$$2x\cdot \binom{6}{4}\cdot 1^2\cdot \left(-\frac 32\right)^2\cdot x^2.$$

Comment: After I simplify this, how do I get the value of k??  Do I equate to zero??

Comment: You add both terms and equal to zero because the assumption is that there is no term $x^3.$ Thus you get the value of $k.$